# Getting "ReferenceError: unescape is not defined" when trying to call() a smart contract method from rasberry pi to a private geth network

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-invocation, raspberry-pi

```
> var contract1 = eth.contract(abi).at(address)
undefined
> contract1
{
  abi: [{.....]
 transactionHash: null,
  addRecord: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  getPatientName: function(),
  getPatientRecord: function(),
  initialize: function(),
  patients: function()
}
> contract1.getPatientRecord(1,1)
```

This throws unescape not defined error.
I can run this on my ubuntu machine but not on my rasberry pi. The web3 version in geth is 0.20.1 which is the same in ubuntu. I don't know what's the issue.

Comment: Same issue here: <pre><code>
var c = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMultiplier","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"m","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setMultiplier","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Multiply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_multiplier","type":"uint256"}],"

Comment: Having same error. Please provide fix if available

Answer (score 0):

Geth has switched to new javascript intepreter in 1.9.11 (Goja) that doesn't (didn't) have the escape/unescape function

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20693

Wait for a new geth release to get this fixed or use geth-unstable as the fix for this is merged already.